# Removing a Div removes the onclick of other div's?

Tags: javascript, onclick

got kind of a strange behavior here.

```
(function(){
    var images=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].parentNode.onclick = function () {
            var embed = "whatever";
            document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="overlay"><div class="game">' + embed + '</div></div>' + document.body.innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('overlay').onclick = function () { this.parentNode.removeChild(this); }
        }
    }
})();
```

this offcourse is simplified code.
after the overlay is clicked,
the overlay (and the contests) is removed.
but the images onclick evens dont work anymore.
any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the following line:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '...' + document.body.innerHTML;
```

Here you concatenate HTML content directly as a string with removing all events bound to all the elements including your images.

Instead of changing `innerHTML` property I would recommend you to create overlay block dynamically and prepend it to `body`.

Comment: this is the code for the overlay, not for the images on click (which are not inside it)

Comment: ok, so since i rewrite the whole `body` everything looses events?

Comment: it's generally not a good idea to do a **.innerHTML = **.innerHTML.  While it seems like you should be able to do it, assigning the innerHTML property has side effects.

Comment: @Dementic It's not possible to serialise the event data when turning parts of the DOM into a string (well, not without inline handlers, which suck).